# Magento gives 404 on every page, including homepage

Tags: magento, migration, http-status-code-404

I have just followed the following steps for a Magento migration.

- Copied all fiels from our staging server to the production server
- Dumped the database and copied it to the production server
- Imported database dump into new database
- Updated app/etc/local.xml
- Updated the database entries "web/secure/base_ur" and "web/unsecure/base_url" to the new url
- Cleared var/cache

Now each page gives a 404 error, including the homepage and admin. Also, it does not seem to be a htaccess problem because urls with index.php in the path also don't work.

I have done the same procedure as listed about on my a different machine with the same files, and then it works fine. So it seems server specific.

I have done extensive searching on the problem, but nothing seems to help so far.

Any ideas  are greatly appriciated!

--edit--
I somewhat fixed it.

In index.php I changed:

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
To
Mage::run('english');

This seems to be necessary as english is the name of our default store. However, I think it would be better if Magento figures this out by itself. Also, how come this worked out of the box when migrating to another server?

Comment: this could be apache issue, I remember similiar issue die to the fact something was turned off by default in new version on the new server and didn't recognize the 'default' magento config so I had to alter vhost/htaccess for magento to recognize what config I've been running. unfortunately software config differs from host to host, even from version to version so developers have to do a lot of debugging to figure it out. sorry to hear you were the one of them too ;)

Comment: @janmyszkier if you can please share informatin over configuring apache to get rid of the issue, that will be great help. thank you. :-)